# powershell arguments with nrpe

Tags: powershell, nrpe

I want to pass two arguements with a powershell-script.

This is the regular check

test = cmd /c echo scripts\test.ps1 ; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -

This is the idea that i want. To set warning and critical.

test = cmd /c echo scripts\test.ps1 **-w 10** **-c  50** ; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -

If warning is set to over 10 then it will return exit 1

If critical is set over 50 then it will return exit 2

Not sure howto do this in my script.

Here is how it looks now.

```
$condition = (Get-Service | Where-Object Status -eq "Running").Count

if ($argument warn) {
    Write-Output "Warning:" $condition
    exit 1 
}

ElseIf ($argument critical) {
        Write-Output "Critical:" $condition
        exit 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not quite sure if this is what you mean, but you can start the script with a **param()** block so it accepts arguments like

```
param (
    [int]$WarningLevel = 0,
    [int]$CriticalLevel = 0
)

$condition = (Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}).Count

if ($CriticalLevel -gt 0 -and $condition -gt $CriticalLevel) {
    Write-Output "Critical: Way too many proc's: $condition"
    Exit 2
}
elseif ($WarningLevel -gt 0 -and  $condition -gt $WarningLevel) {
    Write-Output "Warning: proc's filling up: $condition"
    Exit 1 
}
Write-Output "All OK"
Exit 0
```

Comment: If the script is stored as say `D:\Test\script.ps1`, you can call it like `powershell -File "D:\Test\script.ps1" -WarningLevel 10 -CriticalLevel 50`. P.S. I have edited the code, because I somehow forgot a closing curly bracket before.

Comment: Thanks @Theo. This is what i wanted.

Comment: Will do! But something came up. powershell -File .\test.ps1

Critical: Way too many proc: 116
If i dont enter any arguments it should be OK

Comment: @Larsvontrierpung Well, that is the output if more than 50 services are in the running state. The number 50 is a very low number to provide. On my pc at the moment there are 104. Determine what number you find critical and adjust the value accordingly like `powershell -File "D:\Test\script.ps1" -WarningLevel 100 -CriticalLevel 200`. They are parameters **you** decide after all.

Comment: Because 116 will always be more than 0. So when i just just run the script with no arguments at all, i want it to return Exit 0 so it will tell you that the check is ok. Something like that. And when i enter -WarningLevel 10 -CriticalLevel 20, it should work as it does.

Comment: Even if it's 1000procs running, and with no arguments added, i want it to return OK :)

Comment: Thats it. I will look into it and learn. Really helpful. Have a great evening @Theo

Comment: Thanks for last time. Do you also know how i can monitor a folder that is modified? Not by count or size. I want to get a alarm if a specific folder is modified. If a file copies into that folder or so. If i use count or size, then i need to delete the file in that folder to get rid of the alarm. I have found something about "New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher". This is also for nrpe/nsclient++ in windows with powershell. If folder=modified, return critical. And again. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982743/nrpe-check-send-alarm-if-folder-is-modified

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

`powershell -file "(Path to your PowerShell Script).ps1 -w10 -c50"`

and inside your PowerShell script at the top, insert the following:

`param ($w, $c)`

and then use the variables in your script.

Learn more about named parameters, so you do not have to enter the arguments in order of them being used, and less chance of your script breaking when you want to make changes.

Comment: Thanks @Shaqil Ismail :)